Black tar-like stuff leaking under the window
I have multiple windows that are leaking black tar-like stuff under them. Please see the photos:


Someone told me that it is probably from the window flashing tape; the builder/installer might have used some tar-like tape, which is melting and leaking now.
My house is scheduled for repainting the exterior. The painter said he could clean them up, but I'm worried that without a permanent solution, this issue will persist.
Is it really melting tar from the window flashing tape? The house is less than 20 years old. Is it normal, and do I have to fix it? If it is really due to window flashing and needs to be fixed, do I have to reinstall all those windows, which will be very expensive, or is there some easy way to fix it?
Appreciate any suggestions!

Are the windows new?  Have you had extreme heat this year compared to other years the windows have been installed?  Does the sun hit that wall?  Sun plus extra heat might cause tar to flow.

The windows are the original windows, less than 20 years old.  It started with one or two windows.  But it is getting worse over the last couple of years.  The house side in the photo is under direct sunlight.

This is a cosmetic issue.  Clean off as much as you can and paint.
There is no realistically and financially sound way to mitigate the issue. It would require removal and reinstallation of the exterior cladding.

If tar, it usually requires mineral sprites, diesel fuel or similar to clean.  Test on a hidden section before using.
